# Tkinter form lags in showing data while scrolling

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I have small GUI application with Tkinter. very simply the code is getting a List of options and shows them as a checkbox to the user and waits for user selection.
for performing my task I put a canvas and the a frame inside that and then bind the scrollbar too canvas, Also as I had unknown number of check boxes first I put all of them in a label and then putting the label on my Frame.
everything works and scrollbar too.
but there is a small problem, which is : When I open the windows I have my list on form but when I scroll they are having "**Lag**" and do not appear on my form BUT they appear as I **hover** the mouse on the area.(like classical windows freezing).

Code:

```
class StartPage(tk.Frame):
testListOut = []
def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    self.testList = []
    self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, borderwidth=2, relief="sunken")
    self.frame = tk.Frame(self.canvas)
    self.scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(self.canvas, orient="vertical", command=self.canvas.yview)
    self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar.set)
    self.scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")
    self.canvas.pack(side="top", fill="both" ,expand="true")
    self.canvas.create_window((4, 4), window=self.frame, anchor="nw",tags="self.frame")
    self.frame.bind("<Configure>", self.onFrameConfigure)
    self.populateCheckBox(lNames)
    
def populateCheckBox(self ,testList):
    self.checks = []
    self.vars = []
    label = tk.Label(self.frame , width=3, borderwidth="1")
    label.pack()
    for element in testList:
        var = tk.BooleanVar()
        var.set(False)
        checkbox = tk.Checkbutton(label, relief="flat")
        checkbox["text"] = element
        checkbox["command"] = lambda: self.handler(testList)
        checkbox["variable"] = var
        checkbox.grid(sticky="w",  padx="10", pady="5")
        self.checks.append(checkbox)
        self.vars.append(var)
        
def onFrameConfigure(self, event):
    self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))
```

While opening the Page

[image]

While scrolling

[image]

Comment: Whats the point here to place the `tk.Checkbutton(label,...` into a `tk.Label(...`?

Comment: @stovfl As I have multiple check-buttons I am putting all of them on a Label and then put the Label on the Frame

Comment: Could not reproduce your issue, your [mcve] does not work for me. Try, change to `self.canvas.bind("<Configure>",...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the comment of @stovfl I understood that I have some secondary extra labels.

I just omitted the label inside populateCheckBox() function and put my checkboxes directly on the frame on canvas.

change to : checkbox = tk.Checkbutton(self.frame, relief="flat")